# Unity open external link

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

By placing the unity file on the page I can not redirect the action to another page. What happens is that the new page is opened inside the frame intended for the unity file.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Urlazerecovelo : MonoBehaviour {

 void OnMouseDown ()

{

 Application.OpenURL("https://www.google.pt");

  }

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i need insert a unity file in web page, that on click over , open the url in another tab. Is possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class OpenWebPage : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Application.ExternalEval("window.open('www.google.pl', '_blank');");
    }
}
```

I assume from what you're saying you use WebGL as target platform. More about [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html)